# WebApp Document Preview on Local Area Network

Tags: javascript, backend, document-preview

I'm facing for the first time against document preview in web applications.
I've seen a lot of implementations (Google Document Viewer,ISSUU and others) but they need to work,of course,with a server interface towards Internet.
I'm developing a webapp for big clients that need preview of their documents without permit documents exit from the lan.A connection could be a possible security threat and documents need to remain private.

Do you know if is there a client(js) or server implementation that work on his own?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm talkin about xls/doc/ppt documents.For pdf documents there are no problems!